# Special character ok in HTML, not ok in PDF

Tags: freemarker

The below code in the template takes care that these special characters are printed ok when printed in HTML

```html
?replace("≥", "&GreaterEqual;")?replace("≤", "&leq;")
```

The result is:
**Test special characters:

Greater_equal ≥

Less_equal ≤**

When I change the output type from HTML to PDF, these characters are not printed anymore:
**Test special characters:

Greater_equal

Less_equal**

How canI make this work with PDF as output type?

Answer (score 0):

```
For the one that could encounter same issue
```

I've had this issue recently and what I've found out is for some fonts there is not character set so it doesn't show greater than equal or other symbols.

However I've tried with **Arial** font and it's working even if you've added it like this: '**≥**'

Long story short, solution would be to update the font with the one that support.